# Inline-block, multiple div?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, the code below allows me to view posts made. And with the CSS I can align the text in this div to be "left-aligned". I need to keep it in a inline-block, or else it will affect everything else. This works great, but only for the first post. The next one isn't affected by the CSS. Look at the screenshot, first 4 lines are the first post, and the others are different post, which are not aligned. [Problem shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtaPa.png)

PHP:

```
    $output .= '<div class="vs-info">';
        if ($event_excerpt != 'yes') {
            $output .= $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
        } elseif (!empty($event_summary)) {
            $output .= apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', $event_summary );
        }  else {
            $output .= $content = apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', get_the_excerpt() );
        }
    $output .= '</div>';
```

CSS:

```
#vs .vs-info {display:inline-block; text-align:left;}
```

Comment: Are you trying to assign to BOTH id='vs' and class='vs-info' ?

Comment: Your question doesn't appear to be directly related to php. Could you you provide a code snippet that reproduces the problem with only HTML and CSS?

Comment: Maybe the content itself is centered? Agreed, a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector statement you've written isn't correct; you're asking for an element of class "vs-info" which is a ***descendant*** of an element with the ID "vs".

Place a comma into your CSS like this:

```
#vs, .vs-info {display:inline-block; text-align:left;}
```

**Now** your CSS will apply to either an element with ID "vs" or an element with class "vs-info", and the DIVs you're creating with your PHP will be assigned to display inline-block.

Comment: Possibly so, but it's not clear whether `.vs-info` are descendants of `#vs`.

Comment: It *would* be helpful for him to answer the question in my comment.  Given that OP says "it works for the first but not the subsequent", I find it the most logical explanation.